# How to convert the "Inf" string in a text file to numeric

Tags: r

I know people have asked something similar here, but I cannot find a  solution yet:

I need to create a vector like this:

```
c <- (1, 2, Inf, 2, -Inf)
```

by reading the content from a file

However, I don't know how to parse Inf and -Inf from text to item in the vector.

can anyone help ? I am flexible with the format of the text file, whatever works.

Comment: What have you tried so far? That will help us figure out what didn't work and why.

Comment: What is actually in your file? Is it a single line with `1, 2, Inf, ...`? Are there brackets, commas, linebreaks, anything else?

Comment: As a side note, it would be nice you made your example result valid R syntax, e.g., `c(1, 2, Inf)`. And it's good practice to avoid `c` as a variable name since it is the name of the most common R function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer can be that `Inf` is a reserved word in `R` language. Hence, you don't need to do anything special for it. Just read the file as usual and `Inf` or `-Inf` will be read as `numeric` automatically.

Lets take few examples and explore it further.

```
# Read form text containing multiple Inf and -Inf
df <- read.table(text =
"ID   Count   Name
1     Inf     A
2     -Inf    B
Inf   100     C
4     101     D",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Verify the out of df
df
#    ID Count Name
# 1   1   Inf    A
# 2   2  -Inf    B
# 3 Inf   100    C
# 4   4   101    D

#Check for type of columns containing Inf and -Inf. Type is numeric.
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ ID   : num  1 2 Inf 4
# $ Count: num  Inf -Inf 100 101
# $ Name : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"

#Perform is.infinite checking. It comes TRUE as expected.
is.infinite(df$ID)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE


is.infinite(df$Count)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert "Inf" in a text file to Inf, the number, just wrap `"Inf"`, the product of you reading the file, in a `as.numeric("Inf")`. So read the file as normal, and then throw the whole vector in an `as.numeric()`.

For instance, using `fread()` from `data.table`, if you have a text file whose contents look like:

1 2 Inf

And the file is called `test.txt`, you would do:

```
as.numeric(fread("test.txt"))
```